# How Should I Store Brown Sugar?

Tags: storage-method, brown-sugar

How can I store brown sugar as it always gets hard before I can use it all. How do you store brown sugar? Does it need to be refrigerated?  Also, How can you make hard brown sugar soft again?

Comment: See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/3935/67 and https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/8902/67

Answer (score 1):

I always store brown sugar in an airtight, ziplock bag. That works pretty well for preventing it from getting hard. It does not need to be refrigerated.

However, if your brown sugar is already hard, there are a few techniques that people often recommend for resoftening it. These include: storing it in a closed container for a short period of time with apple slices (which will impart moisture); doing the same with a slice of bread (which will also impart some moisture); or, briefly microwaving it.

Here is a cooking blog which discusses some of these approaches: 
https://www.thekitchn.com/4-ways-to-soften-brown-sugar-and-keep-it-that-way-195922

Comment: Dani, good info but beware of just giving links for information -- they often suffer from 'link rot' when a website shuts down or decides to reorganize their content without setting up redirection.  I suggest giving them credit by linking to them, but also copying out the relevant parts.  (if you put a '`> `' (greater-than and a space)  at the beginning of each paragraph, it'll get formatted as a block quote)

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in the microwave.  One minute at a time to make sure it doesn't melt.  Softens it right up.

If you store it in an airtight container at room temperature that's good enough.