# Brick of Brown Sugar

Tags: brown-sugar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to store brown sugar without it becoming hard?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3935/how-to-store-brown-sugar-without-it-becoming-hard)

If I don't use brown sugar quickly it gets hard.  I mean brick-hard.  I've tried re-sealing bags, and putting it in crocks, it didn't make any difference.

Any suggestions on how to keep this from happening?

Any way to un-brick my current bag?