# How can I store muscovado for longer once opened?

Tags: storage-method, sugar, brown-sugar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to store brown sugar without it becoming hard?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3935/how-to-store-brown-sugar-without-it-becoming-hard)

Muscovado always comes in packs much larger than needed for most recipes, and even though I keep it in as airtight container as possible, I find it goes very, very hard. How can I prolong its shelf life?